# What are options for a Windows laptop with a screen less then 12 inches for basic programming?

Tags: laptop, development

What are options for a laptop with a screen less then 12 inches that runs Windows 10? I'm looking for something ultra portable to do basic programming using a text editor and WSL. I'm hoping for at least 4 gigs of ram and a 128 gig ssd. Screen quality is not an issue since I'm blind. I'd rather pay less and not get a 4k screen.

Comment: Budget? Also, what about something like the [Kangaroo](http://www.kangaroo.cc/kangarooplus/)? I'm not sure if it has a mic, but something like that–ultra-portable with a battery–could be pretty killer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options with those specifications. I'll assume that you're looking for minimum weight and maximum battery life. A two-in-one is probably your best bet for that—that is, tablet plus laptop configuration. Or a tablet with a keyboard.

- You might consider the Surface Pro. It comes with up to 16 GB of RAM (but you can probably configure it with only 4 GB if you want), and it should have a long battery life: Microsoft claims that you can play video for over 13 hours. The current generation is actually 12.3 inches, but it should be much lighter than most laptops. It should have a pretty good processor, too.

  Four gigabytes of RAM, an i5, and a 128 GB SSD should be about $1000. You are paying a bit for screen quality there, though, which might not be ideal - there are cheaper options with lower-quality screens.
- If price plus battery life is your main concern, and you don't care much about performance or having a fairly up-to-date processor, you have much lower-priced options. For example, the [Samsung Galaxy Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XPM5JX2) is another tablet-computer combo, is  about $630, and has a  10.6 inch screen with 4 GB RAM and a 128 GB SSD. It claims 11 hours of video playback. Or basically any of the ones [here](https://www.amazon.com/s/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_two_brow_2?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A%21493964%2Cn%3A541966%2Cn%3A13896617011%2Cn%3A565108%2Cp_n_size_browse-bin%3A13580786011%2Cp_n_feature_five_browse-bin%3A7817222011%2Cp_n_feature_two_browse-bin%3A610553011&bbn=565108&ie=UTF8&qid=1527442121&rnid=562234011) will be cheaper than the Surface Pro.